# StreamWriter.Write doesn't write to file; no exception thrown

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-io, streamwriter.write

My code in C# (asp.net MVC)

```
StreamWriter tw = new StreamWriter("C:\\mycode\\myapp\\logs\\log.txt");

// write a line of text to the file
tw.Write("test");
```

The file is created but is empty. No exception is thrown. I have never seen this before and I am stuck here; I just need to write some debugging output.

Please advise.

Comment: Just in case it helps people have an insight, what language? (presumably C++ or C#)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"path\te.txt", "text");
```

Comment: this is the best answer - if you know that the output content will be no so large..

Answer (score 72):

StreamWriter is buffered by default, meaning it won't output until it receives a Flush() or Close() call.

You can change that by setting the [AutoFlush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.autoflush%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) property, if you want to.  Otherwise, just do:

```
StreamWriter tw = new StreamWriter("C:\\mycode\\myapp\\logs\\log.txt");

// write a line of text to the file
tw.Write("test");
tw.Close();  //or tw.Flush();
```

Comment: I had this same issue- couldn't figure out why it was not writing even though everything was correct. Did not know about the flush/close. I think this is the best answer overall. (I know this is old)

Answer (score 8):

You need to either close or flush the StreamWriter after finishing writing.

```
tw.Close();
```

or

```
tw.Flush();
```

But the best practice is to wrap the output code in a using statement, since StreamWriter implements IDisposable:

```
using (StreamWriter tw = new StreamWriter("C:\\mycode\\myapp\\logs\\log.txt")){
// write a line of text to the file
tw.Write("test");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Neither flushed nor closed nor disposed.
try this

```
using (StreamWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\mycode\myapp\logs\log.txt"))
{
    // write a line of text to the file
    tw.Write("test");
    tw.Flush();
}
```

or my preference

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream( @"C:\mycode\myapp\logs\log.txt"
                                     , FileMode.OpenOrCreate
                                     , FileAccess.ReadWrite)           )
{
    StreamWriter tw = new StreamWriter(fs);
    tw.Write("test");
    tw.Flush();
}
```

Comment: You don't need to run "tw.Flush()" in your first code piece. StreamWriter implements IDisposable with means when the using block ends, it is disposed of automatically.

Comment: Also in your second code piece, I would create tw in using statement too so I don't have to worry about flushing/closing it.

Comment: Flush will only happen if it's on automatic, and that wasn't there when I started using this pattern a lot. Just habit I developed back in olden times that stuck with me.

Answer (score 3):

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("d:\\demo.txt", FileMode.CreateNew,
                               FileAccess.Write);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
int data;

sw.Write("HelloWorld");

sw.Close();
fs.Close();
```

- The problem is when StreamWriter Object is created with reference of FileStream Object , SW object will be always expecting some data till SW object is Closed.
- So After using **sw.Close();**
  Your Opened File will get closed and get ready for showing Output.

Answer (score 2):

Ya in VB.net this was not needed but it seems with CSharp you need a Writer.Flush call to force the write. Of course Writer.Close() would force the flush as well.

We can also set the AutoFlush Property of the StreamWriter instance:

```
sw.AutoFlush = true;
// Gets or sets a value indicating whether the StreamWriter 
// will flush its buffer to the underlying stream after every  
// call to StreamWriter.Write.
```

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.autoflush(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

an alternative

```
FileStream mystream = new FileStream("C:\\mycode\\myapp\\logs\\log.txt",    
FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);           
StreamWriter tw = new StreamWriter(mystream); 
tw.WriteLine("test");
tw.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to close the file or add `\n` to the line such as

```
tw.WriteLine("test");
tw.Close();
```