# How to write the username in a local txt file when login success and check on file for next login?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I want to create a local txt file and store username after login success and for next login the app will check on this file if the username exists for bypass login. But it seems like no file created when I testing it

```
 bool bRet = ws.RequestMemberLogin(1, userName.Text, pass.Text, "", "");

 string path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

 string filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "user.txt");

            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filename);

            bool exist = fi.Exists;
            if (bRet)
            {
                if (exist)
                {
                    // Read
                    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(filename))
                    {
                        string content = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(content);
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    // Write
                    using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(filename, true))
                    {
                        streamWriter.WriteLine(userName.Text);
                    }

                }

             Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(datalist));
             StartActivity(intent);

            }
            else
            {
                error.Text = "Invalid username or password!";

            }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [StreamWriter.Write doesn't write to file; no exception thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023868/streamwriter-write-doesnt-write-to-file-no-exception-thrown)

Comment: _"But it seems like no file created"_ - it seems like or you sure that no file was created?

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: no error but the cache folder is empty

Comment: Can you debug and confirm save path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> string path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

the path will like

```
"/data/user/0/packagename/files/user.txt"
```

As you save it to [Internal Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/#working-with-internal-storage),you couldn't see the files without root permission,if you want to view it,you could use `adb` tool (application signed by Android Debug)

```
adb shell
run-as packagename
cd /data/data/packagename
cd files
ls
```

then you could see the `user.txt`

or you could save it to [External storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/external-storage?tabs=windows),then you could find it in your device File Manager:

```
//"/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/packagename/files/user.txt"
string path = Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir(null).ToString();
```