# PCLStorage NuGetPackage not allow creating folder or file on device

Tags: c#, file, xamarin.forms, local-storage, storage

I have a problem with creating folder with nuget package PCLStorage, I cannot create folder.
Nothing appear inside my files folder. I,m using my device not emulator there is android version 8.0

```
public async Task WriteDataAsync(string filename, string data)
        {
            string folderName = "SignatureSotrage";
            IFolder folder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;

            folder = await folder.CreateFolderAsync(folderName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        }
```

Here is a code where I run this function:

```
public ICommand AddCustomerCommand => new Command(async () =>
        {
            Signature = await SignatureFromStream();
            // Signature should be != null

            var customer = new Customer()
            {
                FullName = this.FullName,
                IsAccepted = this.IsAccepted,
                Birthday = this.Birthday
            };

            if(Signature != null)
            {
                customer.Image = this.Signature.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Błąd", "Nie wszystkie pola zostały poprawnie wypełnione", "OK");
                return;
            }
            await DependencyService.Get<IFileHelper>().WriteDataAsync("signature.txt", "this is file");
            //_context.Customers.Add(customer);
            //_context.SaveChanges();
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

did you debug your code & check if the file/folder is actually getting created by your code or else it enters the catch block and goes with the normal flow?

Check for UserPermissions every time for reading & write permission before doing any operations on the storage. You can add the Nugget packet `Plugin.Permission` it handles everything for you, it adds both the permission in the manifest.

For checking user permissions always try calling CheckForStoragePermissions() before performing any operations on storage.(*DialogService is CustomDialogBox)

```
           if( !await CheckForStoragePermissions() ) 
            {
                DialogService.Alert("Invalid Permission", "User declined permission for this action");
                return;
            }


    private async Task<bool> CheckForStoragePermissions()
    {
        PermissionStatus storagePermissionStatus = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Storage);
        if (storagePermissionStatus != PermissionStatus.Granted)
        {
            Dictionary<Permission, PermissionStatus> storagePermissionResult = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Permission.Storage);
            if (storagePermissionResult.ContainsKey(Permission.Storage))
            {
                storagePermissionStatus = storagePermissionResult[Permission.Storage];
            }
        }
        return storagePermissionStatus == PermissionStatus.Granted;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I test the sample code on GitHub. https://github.com/dsplaisted/PCLStorage

Based on my test the folder path would like:

```
/data/user/0/PCLStorage.Test.Android/files/
```

It is a internal storage. You couldn't see the files without root permission. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/#working-with-internal-storage

If you want to see the files in internal storage, you could use adb tool. Please refer to the way in the link. [How to write the username in a local txt file when login success and check on file for next login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56966590/how-to-write-the-username-in-a-local-txt-file-when-login-success-and-check-on-fi/56981010#56981010)